# How to check RTCPeerConnection is connected or not

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, socket.io, webrtc

How to check RTCPeerConnection is connected or not This is my code:

```
  var myPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
        iceServers: [   {   
               urls: [ "stun:bn-turn1.xirsys.com" ]
        },
        {   
           username: "CV9qLgwJ4tBIm88dyPQJ5HIKK7137bsjn- 
           NikgprJGcp50ZyTxejHtqZlIfYCgUjAAAAAF9lpexhc2hpc2gxOTky",
           credential: "d9b50174-fa41-11ea-8957-0242ac140004",
            urls: [
                "turn:bn-turn1.xirsys.com:80?transport=udp", 
                "turn:bn-turn1.xirsys.com:3478?transport=tcp"
            ]
        }
    ]
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

This will give you the state of a connection, read it, and use it accordingly:

```
var connectionState = myPeerConnection.connectionState;
```

Here is the sample how you can check it, "new" state means it is gathering addresses. check whether you have configured it with right values.

```
myPeerConnection.addEventListener('connectionstatechange', event => {
    if (myPeerConnection.connectionState === 'connected') {
        // Peers connected!
    }
});
```

Comment: i have used this it's return 'new'